# Speed and performance optimisation problem: Multiple database model vs single database

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing, summary

I have an application which is essentially a test-taking system for schools. Students take tests. Teachers track tests. Currently, we have a single db (mysql) to store all information. As users have grown, the performance is very slow. The decision now is whether to go for a single db per school, or to somehow optimise our existing single db. Our question is as to whether performance optimisation is even possible/recommended with a single db, and up to 1000 schools. To give an idea of the data being handled: Currently there are about 1000 schools signed up, but only 40-50 schools using the system actively. With this, the rows in the student table exceed 8000, but it is the table with student_answers (logging answers to quizzes) that already exceeds 70k, and there lies the problem. Similarly we have a quiz-takers table (which records every quiz taken by every user) which is also exceeding 70,000 rows.

We would value any comments on the following

1. Would it be better, given the anticipated figures above, to go for a db per school, or is it possible for a single db to work efficiently, **assuming 2000 ACTIVE schools** (multiplying the figures that we have for 40 schools to match that for 2000)
2. If the answer to the above is that a single db and optimisation is easily possible, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated in terms of creation of summary tables, indexing and more, specifically

a) what would a summary table for students, student_answers look like?

The bulk of the data is found in these two tables
1. quiz_takers
2. student_answers

The current table structure (data dictionary) can be found on the link below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13WxRgmOxkRWcYV238tZJzgFSDV7fWK0J/view?usp=sharing

Note the indexes already applied (that is what we have already tried) but performance is still not optimal.

Our main and primary question is whether a single db design for this level of usage (2000 active schools) is feasible and can be sufficiently optimised.

Comment: *"Note the indexes already applied (that is what we have already tried) but performance is still not optimal."*  Does MySQL also use a index thats the question -> `EXPLAIN query` and post the results and the queries here..   MySQL should be able to handle millions or even billions of records in a single table just fine when indexed and MySQL uses the index.

Comment: also instead of a document -> `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question/queries and post the results here..

Comment: Raymond - I'm afraid nothing you've said is clear. I know mysql can handle it...but that's not my question exactly. Also - don't understand what you mean  by explain query/show create ... :)

Comment: [explain query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) generates a query plan so we can see if MySQL indeed is using the index for your query.. And [SHOW CREATE TABLE table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html) generates a `CREATE TABLE` structure so we can see and use the table yourself to test some things.. Also we need to know which queries you execute *"I'm afraid nothing you've said is clear."* More easy then this i can't explain as this is a performance question we need this information otherwise the question is simply total unclear for us..

Comment: Thanks - will ammend as best I can (keeping in mind I'm the founder/owner not developer) so was approaching the question less technically.

Answer (score 1):

**One vs many Databases**

The term "database" may mean "server" or may refer to **CREATE DATABASE**.  In the latter case:

```
SELECT ... FROM dbname.tblname ...
```

is just as fast as

```
USE dbname;
...
SELECT ... FROM tblname ...
```

So, it does not matter whether your tables are in the same database or different databases.

If you are referring to **different servers** (computers), then the is a big difference.

Another approach is to put all the schools into a **single table**, with an extra column for `school_id`.  This is often the best.  But, I sense that that would be more work than desired, I will assume you have

- One MySQL instance (on one server)
- Many `DATABASEs`, one per "school"
- Each `DATABASE` has several tables for info about that school.

**Bottom Line**  To address performance problems, we need to see the queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It could be as simple as missing some indexes.

Suitably indexed, even a 70K-row table, is a "small" table.

**Summary tables?**  For billion-row tables, I strongly encourage the use of summary tables.  For 70K rows, it may be useful.  Want do you want to summarize?  What is the table you would be summarizing?

**Schema**  OK, you have pictures of the schema.  That is hard to work with.  And `DESCRIBE` is less descriptive than `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I don't see many secondary keys?  No wonder you are having performance problems.  Show us one `SELECT` that `JOINs` two or more tables and has a `WHERE`; we will discuss what other indexes are needed.

Comment: Could you explain SHOW CREATE TABLES ...or a youtube video/article that demos how to do this in order to improve my question...your thoughts were very helpful for a start